# How to use multiple update queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to update `Data_type` where `Data_Type` contains Null or strings except D
if there is any string how could i code it

```
Update Table_Name
Set Data_Type='D'
Where Data_type is Null 
   or Data_type = ' ' or like Data_type %[A-C]% or Data_Type %[e-z]%
Go
--
```

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is wrong. Should be

```
Update Table_Name
Set    Data_Type = 'D'
Where  Data_Type <> 'D'
and    src_hm    <> 1
and   (
       Data_type is Null 
or     Data_type = ' ' 
or     Data_type like %[A-C]% 
or     Data_Type like %[e-z]%
      )
```

Comment: Cool thanks man and if i want to put this into procedure if Data_type <> D then update and src_hm <>1 then update how can i code this ?